# My Servlet Endpoint returns JSON but my AXIOS function doesnt run and fetch it for my webpage

Tags: javascript, java, json, servlets, axios

I have a simple HTML form

```
<form action="#" method="get" id="thisForm">
       <button type="submit"> GetJSON </button>
</form>
```

This is my javascript at the end portion of my body tag

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js">

let form = document.getElementById("thisForm");
form.addEventListener('submit', servletAccess())

function servletAccess(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("im here")


    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/Project1/MyServlet')
    .then(function (response) {
      // handle success
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // handle error
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function () {
      console.log(response);
    });
}
    


</script>
```

and this is my java servlet returning JSON

```
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
    
    JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
    user.put("name", "rous");
    user.put("age", 26);
    user.put("lname", "e");
    
    JSONObject user2 = new JSONObject();
    user.put("name", "rene");
    user.put("age", 28);
    user.put("lname", "solomon");
    
    json.put(user);
    json.put(user2);
    
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
```

When directly going to my endpoint by URL, i get the RAW data

[{"lname":"solomon","name":"rene","age":28},{}]

so i know my endpoint works.

How come i couldnt even console.log the response?
my dummy  console.log("im here") is not even running?

This might be very simple but im stuck with it.

Comment: Open the network tab in your browser's dev tools with your website open and see if the call to the endpoint is successful. If not, what error is being thrown? You will only be able to see the call if the call is made while the network tab is open

Comment: @Sal actually nothing happens after my button click. not even an error is appearing

Comment: Ok, so a couple of things to check in that case - 

1. Are there any errors in the console?. 

2. is `servletAccess` even being called on click? If not, maybe try adding `onclick="servletAccess(event)"` on the `submit` element instead.

Comment: im using axios wrong pointed out by the answer below. you both helped me. appreciate it! its giving CORS error now so its good. appreciate it man

Comment: By default, Chrome blocks any calls to external urls if it they are different from the client, whether in protocol (`http` vs `https`), the domain, or the port (the servlet is running on `8080` but your application is running on `80`). You need to configure CORS on your server to let your browser know that it is allowed to access the resource. Try adding `response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`, where `"*"` says that any browser, protocol, domain, port can access the resource. You can limit it to a specific call origin, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: appreciate it man, i configured my web.xml to allow access. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script tag specified 'src' and also inline javascript, when you write it like this your inline js will be ignored, so you have to separate those script tags:

```js
<script src='path/to/axios/'></script>
<script>
// register your form handler
</script>
```

Also this line:

```js
form.addEventListener('submit', servletAccess())
```

You registering actual function call as event listener, instead it should be function itself, like this:

```js
// notice no () at the end of function name
form.addEventListener('submit', servletAccess)
```

Comment: tried this initially, and tried it again now. still does not work...

Comment: updated my answer, sorry for not complete answer in the beginning

Comment: appreciate it man! using axios wrong. now i have CORS error but i can handle that. thank you!